# Dapper - enumerable sequence of parameters is not allowed

Tags: c#, dapper

Dapper keeps giving me the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context'

Here is the code:

```
var ids = result.Result.Select(x => new { x.Id } );

 query = @"
        SELECT [A], [B], [C]
        FROM [MyTable]
        WHERE [C] IN @Ids
    ";

var resultTwo = Connection.Query<MyObject>(query, ids)?.ToList();
```

I have also tried:

```
    var ids = result.Result.Select(x => x.Id );
```

Comment: Did you try to materialize the _var ids_ adding a _ToList();_ to your linq expression?

Comment: @Steve I have tried that, same error.

Comment: Try passing `new { ids }` instead of `ids` to the query method.

Comment: @JessedeWit that solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to run a query like yours with the help of the DynamicParameters

```
var ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@ids", ids);
var recs = cnn.Query<City>("SELECT * FROM Cities Where IDCity in @ids", parameters);
```

This make me think that (as already explained in a comment above) the problem is in the missing *new {ids}* so it could be simply

```
var resultTwo = Connection.Query<MyObject>(query, new { ids} )?.ToList();
```

Comment: `DynamicParameters` worked for me in `interface` to `class` scenario where `parameters` would be unknown in   
`protected virtual async Task<List<T>> DapperListAsync(string sql, object param = null)`  
scenario.